# Cannot change filename using File.renameTo() on GNU/Linux

Tags: java, linux, file

I encounter a strange problem while coding. I have to rename file named `börsenzeitung_komplett` to `processed_börsenzeitung_komplett`.

I am using `currentFile.renameTo(newFile)` from Java API, **which is working fine on Windows system but returning false on GNU/Linux system.**

Comment: Did you check the read/write permissions on source file and destination directory?

Comment: Maybe the user who run java application has no permission to rename that file. try: chmod 777 filename .

Comment: If you have some solution, please share with me. I have now the same problem. You have got a +1 for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the privileges of the output directory (and optionaly change it using [chmod](http://catcode.com/teachmod/)) or if the destination file already exist (I assume that you're not using any `SecurityManager`).

As [java.util.File Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) says:

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   **platform-dependent**: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and **it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists**. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a
>   file in a platform independent manner.

Comment: The problem in of Special character in the file 'börsenzeitung_komplett' ö this character, rest all other files are getting renamed. I am using the linux system, do I need to do some setting in order to support these kind of characters also ??

Comment: Can you rename this file from the GNU/Linux terminal?